# Compile project using Poco(with Crypto/NetSSL enabled) on Windows and crosscompile it on Linux ARM

Tags: windows, cmake, cross-compiling, gitlab-ci, poco-libraries

**Overview:**
I am working on commandline server application (C++) which is using POCO libraries. We had working CI on gitlab compiling this project on Windows x64, Linux x64&x86, Linux arm 32b. We ran client and server on the same machine before, but they want us to make it run over the internet. Due to Poco TCP server utilization it is already possible but I need to integrate encryption( SSL).

After I turned on encryption parts in POCO library project became uncompilable on Windows and ARM because of the OpenSSL dependency. On Linux TCP Server with encryption works fine.

**Windows problems:**
I tried install openSSL in various ways and to different folders, cmake finds it but in the end of compilation there are some files missing. I found on forums that there are changes needed to be made to make POCO run with standard OpenSSL, I do not know what changes (If I knew I would try to do it). I tried to use precompiled OpenSSL from poco library but it throws lot of errors (missing files) during isntallation.
Here is the link on standard OpenSSL I used(not light version, installed both 32 a 64b): https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

**Linux ARM crosscompilation problems:**
This ends up on OpenSSL too (so I decided to write it all in one post despite platform differences). I succesfully compile OpenSSL on ARM platfom from the authors gitlab repo but cmake is unable to find it, even when I am setting cmake system variable to right path. OpenSSL is also installed on the machine (but this hardly helps because it is not arm machine).

EDIT: Problem is possible caused by includes I have all encryption related stuff in one class, includes from .h file:

```cpp
#include "Poco/Net/SocketReactor.h"
#include "Poco/Net/SocketAcceptor.h"
#include "Poco/Net/SocketNotification.h"
#include "Poco/Net/SecureServerSocket.h"
#include "Poco/NObserver.h"
#include "Poco/Exception.h"
#include "Poco/Thread.h"
#include "Poco/FIFOBuffer.h"
#include "Poco/Delegate.h"
#include "Poco/Util/ServerApplication.h"
#include "Poco/Util/Option.h"
#include "Poco/Util/OptionSet.h"
#include "Poco/Util/HelpFormatter.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "ProcessUtils.h"
#include "ServiceHandler.h"
```

.cpp:

```cpp
#include "Poco/Net/Context.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>
#include <thread>
#include <Sleep.h>
#include <common/Version.h>
#include <AppConfig.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <SecuredServerRuntime.h>
```

How I am using it:

```cpp
Poco::Net::Context secureContext(Poco::Net::Context::SERVER_USE, key, certificate, "", Poco::Net::Context::VERIFY_RELAXED, 9, false);
            Poco::Util::Application::instance().logger().information("Listening on IP address %s:%d", this->address, (int)port);
            SecureServerSocket svs(sa, 64, &secureContext);
            SocketReactor reactor;
            SocketAcceptor<ServiceHandler> acceptor(svs, reactor);
```

EDIT 2:

Cmake:

```
list(APPEND LIBRARIES )

#region POCO setup
# list all enabled libraries and set include paths
foreach (POCOLIB Foundation XML Util Net NetSSL Crypto JSON)
        list(APPEND LIBRARIES Poco${POCOLIB})
        target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE lib/Poco/${POCOLIB}/include)
endforeach ()
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBRARIES})
```

in cmake list in dependecies folder is line "include(Poco.cmake)"

Poco.cmake:

```
get_filename_component(THIS_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE} NAME_WE)
message(STATUS "Configuring ${THIS_FILE}")

# and set the options for POCO
set(ENABLE_CPPUNIT OFF CACHE BOOL "Enable the CppUnit" FORCE)
set(ENABLE_XML ON CACHE BOOL "Enable the XML" FORCE)
set(ENABLE_JSON ON CACHE BOOL "Enable the JSON" FORCE)
set(ENABLE_MONGODB OFF CACHE BOOL "Enable MongoDB" FORCE)
set(ENABLE_PDF OFF CACHE BOOL "Enable PDF" FORCE)
set(ENABLE_UTIL ON CACHE BOOL "Enable Util" FORCE)
set(ENABLE_NET ON CACHE BOOL "Enable Net" FORCE)
set(ENABLE_NETSSL ON CACHE BOOL "Enable NetSSL" FORCE)
set(ENABLE_NETSSL_WIN ON CACHE BOOL "Enable NetSSL Windows" FORCE)
set(ENABLE_CRYPTO ON CACHE BOOL "Enable Crypto" FORCE)
set(ENABLE_DATA OFF CACHE BOOL "Enable Data" FORCE)
set(ENABLE_DATA_SQLITE OFF CACHE BOOL "Enable Data SQlite" FORCE)
set(ENABLE_DATA_MYSQL OFF CACHE BOOL "Enable Data MySQL" FORCE)
set(ENABLE_DATA_POSTGRESQL OFF CACHE BOOL "Enable Data PosgreSQL" FORCE)
set(ENABLE_DATA_ODBC OFF CACHE BOOL "Enable Data ODBC" FORCE)
set(ENABLE_SEVENZIP OFF CACHE BOOL "Enable SevenZip" FORCE)
set(ENABLE_ZIP OFF CACHE BOOL "Enable Zip" FORCE)
set(ENABLE_APACHECONNECTOR OFF CACHE BOOL "Enable ApacheConnector" FORCE)
set(ENABLE_CPPPARSER OFF CACHE BOOL "Enable C++ parser" FORCE)
set(ENABLE_POCODOC OFF CACHE BOOL "Enable Poco Documentation Generator" FORCE)
set(ENABLE_PAGECOMPILER OFF CACHE BOOL "Enable PageCompiler" FORCE)
set(ENABLE_PAGECOMPILER_FILE2PAGE OFF CACHE BOOL "Enable File2Page" FORCE)
set(ENABLE_REDIS OFF CACHE BOOL "Enable Redis" FORCE)

# build static
set(POCO_STATIC ${STATIC_LINKING} CACHE BOOL "Set to OFF|ON (default is OFF) to control build of POCO as STATIC library" FORCE)
set(POCO_MT OFF CACHE BOOL "Set to OFF|ON (default is OFF) to control build of POCO as /MT instead of /MD" FORCE)

message(STATUS "POCO static = ${POCO_STATIC}")

# parallel build
#set(ENABLE_MSVC_MP ${${PROJECT_NAME}_PARALLEL_BUILD} CACHE BOOL "Set to OFF|ON (default is OFF) to control parallel build with MSVC" FORCE)

if (NOT TARGET Foundation)
    add_subdirectory(Poco)
endif ()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You want us to help you with your code (In the log I see only the one error: `fatal error: Poco/Net/Context.h: No such file or directory`, and it is caused by compiling your project), but without viewing your code we cannot help. This doesn't imply that we want your production code. No, we want a [mcve] which reproduces your problem.

Comment: @Tsyvarev maybe it is includes, I added example how I am using encryption related parts and that include you mentioned

Comment: Directive `#include "Poco/Net/Context.h"` is most likely a correct one, but It is a `CMakeLists.txt` file which is responsible for correct linking Poco library and adding its include directories, so this inclusion will succeed. That is, the error you got isn't caused by the wrong `.cpp` or `.h`, but caused by the wrong (probably) `CMakeLists.txt` script. But you don't show that script...

Comment: @Tsyvarev Added cmake script parts including POCO. If you need to see other part of code/cmake, just ask I will provide it. I can not upload whole cmake script (and it is too long anyway) but we will find some way if you need whole script with all depedencies includings.

Comment: I see that you add include directories `lib/Poco/${POCOLIB}/include` with `POCOLIB` values taken from the given set. Which include directory **actually** contains `Poco/Net/Context.h` on your machine? That is, the path to the header should be `lib/Poco/${POCOLIB}/include/Poco/Net/Context.h` relative to the current directory.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I corrected it: target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE lib/Poco/NetSSL_OpenSSL/include)
list(APPEND LIBRARIES PocoNetSSL), now I am getting same error as on Linux ARM build: lib\Poco\Crypto\include\Poco/Crypto/Crypto.h(30): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory, i tried set system variables so cmake will be able to find that file: set LIBPATH="C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/lib"
set INCLUDE="C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/include", but it did not help

Comment: In your `CMakeLists.txt` you need to add include directory, which contains `openssl/opensslv.h` header.

Answer (score 1):

```
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} OpenSSL::SSL)
```

Thanks to @Tsyvarev, this solved problem on Windows (with previous modifications I discussed with him in comments).

In case of ARM compilation (which is still not working) this throws error that it cant find OpenSSL, despite I compiled it before and set OpenSSL_ROOT variable.